# ERR unknown command 'GEOADD' from embeded redis in java spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I'm doing unit test in Java Spring Framework where the code needs to use GEOADD operation to filter location that align within 25 kilometers from the origin point.

The implementation is working fine (connect with a real redis' node) but the unit test (which connect to embeded redis) show the following error

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: ERR unknown command 'GEOADD'; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR unknown command 'GEOADD'
```

this is my pom

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

...

<dependencies>

...

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.kstyrc</groupId>
        <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
        <version>0.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Initialize embeded redis in junit test

```
public class EmbeddedRedisServer {

    static RedisServer redisServer = null;

    static {
        try {
            redisServer = new RedisServer(6479);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static RedisServer redisServer() throws IOException {
        return redisServer;
    }

}
```

the test case

```
@BeforeClass
public static void init() throws Exception {
    EmbeddedRedisServer.redisServer().start();
    System.setProperty("spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled", "false");
}

@Test
public void testFindNearByPoint() {
    for (CurrentGeoLocation currentGeoLocation : getCurrentLocationList()) {
        currentGeoLocationService.createOrUpdate(currentGeoLocation);
    }
    List<CurrentGeoLocation> list = nearByDriverService.findNearByPoint(13.392900, 52.491560, null);
    Assert.assertThat(list, hasSize(2));
}

@AfterClass
public static void destroy() throws IOException {
    EmbeddedRedisServer.redisServer().stop();
}
```

The method that's needed to be tested

```
public List<CurrentGeoLocation> findNearByPoint(final Double longitude, final Double latitude,
                                                                                  final List<Long> driverIds) {
    redisTemplate.delete(GeoTrackingConstants.GEO_KEY);
    List<CurrentGeoLocation> geoLocationList = new ArrayList<>();
    final GeoOperations<String, CurrentGeoLocation> geoOpt = redisTemplate.opsForSet().getOperations().opsForGeo();
    List<CurrentGeoLocation> currentGeoLocations =(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(driverIds))? currentGeoLocationService.findAll()
                                                                      : currentGeoLocationService.findAll(driverIds);
    for (CurrentGeoLocation currentGeoLocation : currentGeoLocations) {
        Point point = new Point(currentGeoLocation.getLongitude(), currentGeoLocation.getLatitude());
        geoOpt.geoAdd(GeoTrackingConstants.GEO_KEY, point, currentGeoLocation);
    }
    Point originPoint = new Point(longitude, latitude);
    Circle circle = new Circle(originPoint, new Distance(radius, RedisGeoCommands.DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS));
    final GeoResults<RedisGeoCommands.GeoLocation<CurrentGeoLocation>> result =
            (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(driverIds))? geoOpt.geoRadius(GeoTrackingConstants.GEO_KEY, circle)
            :  geoOpt.geoRadius(GeoTrackingConstants.GEO_KEY, circle, RedisGeoCommands.GeoRadiusCommandArgs.newGeoRadiusArgs().sortAscending());
    List<GeoResult<RedisGeoCommands.GeoLocation<CurrentGeoLocation>>> locations = result.getContent();
    for (GeoResult<RedisGeoCommands.GeoLocation<CurrentGeoLocation>> location : locations) {
        if (location.getContent().getName() != null) {
            geoLocationList.add(location.getContent().getName());
        }
    }
    return geoLocationList;
}
```

Any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Looks like your Redis server is too old - upgrade it.

Answer (score 4):

I guess maybe because your redis version is too low,only redis 3.2 support geo operations.

Comment: When i use the most recent version checked via the maven repository, how do i update the redis?